# What is the importance of Galadriel giving a new bow to Legolas?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, movie, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

In *Fellowship of the Ring*, at the Lothlorien - the place of Galadriel -
 the Fellowship received gifts from Galadriel. Legolas received the Bow of Galadrim replacing his current bow, the Bow of Mirkwood. Now what is the importance of giving a new bow to Legolas? Since it is the same weapon, and the only difference is the **color** of the bow.

[image]
<sub>The Bow of Mirkwood</sub>

[image]
<sub>The Bow of Galadhrim</sub>

As you can see it is the same use of weapon.The only difference is the color.

Comment: You can also see that __it's not the same__. Difference may seem as purely cosmetic, but one must see that the appearance of wooden objects changes with the type of wood and the treatment, and, I imagine, so do the properties - e.g. tensile strength, durability, weight, which affect accuracy and the power of a bow.

Comment: Is this question specifically about the movie adaptation?

Comment: Yes  as you can see the pictures that I posted is from movie canon

Comment: I doubt that there is a clear movies-only answer.

Comment: Neithan,What do you mean

Comment: In the movies, the importance is probably only the honor of receiving the gift.

Comment: Quasi_Stomach, then the giving of legolas new bow would be useless. Because it is just the same use of weapon

Comment: So is giving medals, but receiving one in recognition for what you've done (and usually from someone important) is considered an honor.  I recall that in the book, some of the party only got belts...what's the use in that?

Comment: could be why it was cut out of the theatrical releases in the first place

Comment: Quasi_Stomach ,For celebrating of ther success.But in this case it is not a recognition it for protection of themselves.

Comment: I feel like maybe you're looking for a specific answer --  maybe you should provide your own?

Comment: My answer to my question is it seemed useless when galadriel give the bow of galadhrim to legolas. Because legolas even has a bow of mirkwood already.

Comment: How about this.  She was very proud of their own bows, so she gave one to Legolas 'cause she thought it was better (even if it wasn't)

Comment: Maybe Jackson was anticipating Breath of the Wild and the Galadhrim bow was **Durability +** even if it wasn't stronger

Comment: I've attempted Freudian analysis on this topic but decided to quit while I was ahead

Comment: It's kind of weird to keep judging just for the looks in a world in which people pays hundreds of dollars to change an iPhone for a newer one - which looks _exactly_ the same.

Comment: I don't understand why you say it's the same. Yes, it's a bow, but apart from that it could be completely different and much better than his original one. You can't tell that they're the same just by looking at them! They could look exactly the same in size and color but be made of different wood or just wood treated in a  different manner and so have completely different properties.

Comment: A Stradivarius looks just like any other violin... until you hold it in your own hands.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when Galadriel gives you a bow, it's the last one you'll ever need.

Comment: I was always under the impression that the bow was superior because it was made of mallorn wood, which would only be available in Lórien. I can't find any canonical source for it though.

Comment: Of course the Bow of the Galadrim +5 is better than the Greenwood Bow +3.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Legolas' Mirkwood bow was relatively short, and not especially powerful or long-ranged. From *Fellowship*:

> Arrows fell among them. One struck Frodo and sprang back. Another pierced Gandalf's hat and stuck there like a black feather
>
> ...
>
> Legolas turned and set an arrow to the string, **though it was a long shot for his small bow**.

We can see here that orc bows were powerful and accurate enough to reach the Fellowship at ranges where Legolas' bow would apparently struggle. Later, we get a description of the bow Galadriel gives him:

> To Legolas, she gave a bow such as the Galadhrim used, **longer and stouter** than the bows of Mirkwood, and strung with a string of elf-hair. With it went a quiver of arrows.

A longer, stouter bow is almost by definition going to be more powerful than the short-ranged affair he had been using up to that point. It's not explicit that there was some form of 'magic' in the bow, but given what we know about other elven artefacts it seems likely; in which case, what with the Galadhrim being closer to the elven power of old, one can imagine it has greater virtues than the relatively mundane weapon from Mirkwood.

Comment: During the battle of Balin's tomb, Legolas uses the bow of mirkwood that time. He was able to use it powerfully.

Comment: At short range, yes - at least, enough to penetrate crappy moria-orc armour.

Comment: The bow of Mirkwood was a weapon well suited to the dense forest he grew up in where line of sight was likely less than 30m. But shooting 70 to 90m requires something "stouter".

Comment: The bow of mirkwood can shoot far range especially during the bridge of khazadum when legolas shoots an goblin. It was a far range!

Comment: @anakindchosenone05192005 Only in the film, in which Legolas' abilities were hyped far beyond sanity. But even in the films, the orc he shot from across the chasm was almost unarmoured, while Legolas would soon be going up against heavily-armoured Uruk-hai -a more powerful bow would be needed.

Comment: @Werrf - The OP's whole question is about the film version.

Comment: The performance difference between a good and not so good bow, if both made by professional artisans, might not be very much at all - all else being equal. But a replacement would at least be new, as opposed to used and somewhat worn out.

Comment: Mirroring @Verdan, Growing up I hunted deer in the woods and fields around our ranch. In the woods I used a 444 marlin lever action which had  great power at a short distance but no accuracy at range. Needed to be able to glance off small branches with minimum deflection. When hunting in the open fields I used a 7mm magnum which was very precise at long range.

Answer (score 0):

The difference essentially is like urban combat present day in real war calls for a smaller and more easily maneuvered firearm such as an AR-15, whereas a true ranged warfare artist not entwined in the urban structures (or the dense mirkwoods) would use a larger more powerful firearm such as a 308 Lapua Magnum

Comment: Perhaps you mean _.338_ Lapua? In any case, I don't think any firearms were available to Legolas.

Comment: Sorry I had a type for caliber. I am quite aware of the lack of current weapons but thoughts a more current example may be best used to show the difference

Comment: I'm okay with this answer, but you'll find around here that people want Tolkien answers in Tolkien's Legendarium

Comment: I like this answer.  It shows how Tolkien put a lot of thought into his works by showing a real world corollary.

Comment: Thanks A Bailey. I just wanted to put some in my answer because I figured that would helps some folks from wondering why Tolkien made the Mirkwood bows inferior when it was him being so precise in detail as to include tactical aspects most authors would never consider.

Comment: No military uses the AR-15.